# SQL Server Query SELECT Error (now trying LIMIT)

Tags: sql-server, database, select

I am working on what should be a super simple query for SQL Server 2014. All I want to do is check that our systems can interface with SQL Server after updates, etc. So I need to just verify that it makes the connection correctly and finds a table within the Server.

Attempt 1:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
From [X].[dbo].[Y]
WITH (NOLOCK);
```

But apparently 'top' is not a supported option with SQL Server 2014.
To add some more, here is the exact error I get when trying to run that: Syntax error. The token 'Top' is invalid. Please check the case of your operators (eg 'or' versus 'OR') and check that your functions use brackets after the function name eg Now(), eg Len("abc").

Attempt 2:

```
SELECT *
From [X].[dbo].[Y]
WITH (NOLOCK)
LIMIT (1);
```

That one tells me that I need to put data items between [], text between "", and functions as FunctionName(). However...I don't see where I missed any of those.

Can anybody possibly shed some light on why my query isn't going through? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First thing, please don't use NOLOCK. That will cause you problems that you didn't expect to happen.

Comment: Limit is not supported in SQl Server. Top 1 however is. I can run a query similar to yours in my SQL Server database. What specific error are you getting?

Comment: I was told NOLOCK was a good idea on a heavily trafficked server. Regardless, removing that from either one does not fix the issue.
McNets, I can't try it that way because I'm told 'top' is an invalid token.

Comment: Also how are you running this code? Directly from SSMS or from some application code?

Comment: HLGEM
It says syntax error. The token 'Top' is invalid.

Comment: I'm running it from a different application that interfaces with the Server.

Comment: Then you need to consult the manual or the support team for that "different application" - we can't possibly guess which valid T-SQL constructs it's been coded to understand, but it's certainly wrong that `TOP` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first attempt should work just fine:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
From [dbo].[Y]
WITH (NOLOCK);
```

See [example](http://rextester.com/EHH6477)

If it doesn't work, you should include the error message.

Comment: I updated the question with the exact error message.

Comment: for the "[X]" part, you have properly specific the database name. [Y] must be a valid table name in the dbo schema. The parens around the 1 are unnecessary. And if you're just looking for detection, you can specify just a column name instead of *.  Better yet, you could test for existence in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view instead. But I did a similar statement on my own DB ("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[MyTable]") and it worked fine.

Comment: Aaaaah, I knew it was something stupid like that! Tried it in the format pmbAustin entered it and it works fine. Was just thrown off by the top error. Thank you!

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll give you the checkmark. Don't see an option to upvote comments.